# Catching $resource.ready event

Tags: angularjs

I am using the $resource service in angularjs to asynchronously load json content from the server. When the content is loading I show a gif loader on the page. I need to know when the ansyncronous request is complete so I can remove the loader. How can I catch the ready event so I can remove the loader?

```
function PlaylistController($scope, $route, $http, Song,Artists,Albums,Drive,Children){
    function render(){
        $scope.songs = Song.list()

        //Obviously this removes the loading class immediately
        //I want to remove it when Song.list() is complete
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }

    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function($currentRoute, $previousRoute){
    //When the route changes,update the $scope variables
    render();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do DOM manipulation inside of controller.

What about `$scope.loading = true` and `<body ng-class="loading && 'loading'">`?

When you set `$scope.loading` to true the `loading` class will be added to body, when set to false it will be removed.

If you need to change it from child controllers put it inside of an object(like `$scope.data.loading = true`) or create functions to change it like `$scope.startLoading = function(){ $scope.loading = true; }`

Comment: +1 Angular controllers should not manipulate the DOM if at all possible. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#controller

Comment: But how can I change $scope.loading = false once the content has been loaded. Your method adds the loading class to the body when loading begins, but it never removes it once loading is finished.

Comment: in the controller where you will define `$scope.loading` just call `= false` or create a function like `$scope.stopLoading = function(){ $scope.loading = false }` to child scopes use. ngClass evaluate it expression each $digest. In the digest that loading is false the 'loading' class won't be returned by the evaluation and ngClass will understand that it need to remove it. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/s8JVj/